# Get number of defined element attributes in xml schema

Tags: java, xml, dom, xsd, xerces

I'm using Apache Xerces to parse xml and from some reasons I would need to find how many attributes an element has defined in xsd. element.getAttributes just gives me all present attributes. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

```
DOMImplementationRegistry registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();
XSImplementation impl = (XSImplementation) registry.getDOMImplementation("XS-Loader");
XSLoader schemaLoader = impl.createXSLoader(null);
XSModel xsModel = schemaLoader.loadURI(xsdResource.getURL().getPath());
((XSComplexTypeDecl) xsModel.getComponents(XSTypeDefinition.COMPLEX_TYPE).itemByName(xsdName, "typeName")).getAttrGrp().getAttributeUses();
```